# What is the game system that is based on Marvel Super Heroes RPG?

Tags: product-identification, retro-clones

I know that there is one game system that is based upon the old Marvel Super Heroes RPG, but I forget what the name is. Thus my question is, which system is this?

(It is basically the same ruleset as the old Marvel game from what I remember, but without any setting attached to it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many old Marvel games, but I assume you mean [the old one based on the FASERIP system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_(role-playing_game)) (so named based on the first letters of the 7 primary character attributes).

I know of two recent FASERIP retro-clones:

- [Four Color (4C) System](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/50837/Four-Color-System-Core-Rules)
- [FASERIP](https://faserip.wordpress.com/)

You can also get stuff for the old system at [classicmarvelforever.com](http://www.classicmarvelforever.com/cms/).

Comment: yepp exactly that one was it tnx

Comment: FASERIP's website is no longer available but it appears to be available for download on DriveThru in a 130+ page form (vs. 4C's 30+ page form). 4C is toolkitty but holds very close to the original. FASERIP appears to make some smart choices about what to move forward (design-wise) while keeping 80-90% of its core at the original, and as a "product" is more complete.

Answer (score 2):

That one's called FASERIP, and is [available for download here](https://faserip.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You're most likely thinking of the retroclone [*FASERIP*](https://faserip.wordpress.com/), named after the fan-created nickname for [*Marvel Super Heroes*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwjn7dKmz8THAhUSnYgKHf6cCrI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMarvel_Super_Heroes_(role-playing_game)&ei=LpPcVeeeMJK6ogT-uaqQCw&usg=AFQjCNGr38gp6k8HgNBShd64d1tHBJ1rPw&sig2=nlXmV9c46QfAqsHOAOuXRg) as an acronym of its PCs' stats. It's well-known and -liked by fans of old-school supers. This is a fairly straightforward retroclone, intended to be *Marvel Super Heroes* in all but name.

Less likely, you might instead be thinking of the less-well-known [*Four Color System*](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/50837/Four-Color-System-Core-Rules), another retroclone of *Marvel Super Heroes*. This takes more of a toolkit approach to the original rules, so it's more flexible, but not as immediately playable right out of the box. It's regarded as a useful reference if you're already playing MSH, and as a resource for hacking on the original MSHRPG and other FASERIP games.

Comment: just consciously saw it.....isn't four colors more or less the same (sans the copyrighted things)? is faserip quite different there?

Comment: @ThomasE. The nature of retroclones is that they're always a little bit different than each other. The differences in actual rules appear to be minor (I haven't played either), but differences in layout, writing, inclusion of optional rules or not, etc. can be a big deal as an end-user.

Comment: @ThomasE. Did some more digging. Didn't find any exact cites, but based on opinions and talk around the webs, I've added some “why one or the other” information to the post.